Error while upgrading to azure-identity 1.16.1
We had been using azure-identity 1.10.0 but due to security vulnerabilities we had to upgrade it to 1.16.1. But after upgrading we are getting the below error :
EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
But as soon as we switch back to older version everything works fine. We are using azure DefaultAzureCredential for authentication.
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

Does anyone know why we are getting this?

Please edit your question and include how you’re instantiating DefaultAzureCredential in your code?

I have updated the code @gaurav

What are the environment variables you have set which are used for EnvironmentCredential?


Environment Credential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.

It might not occur only because of Azure identity library version vulnerabilities. As long as the Python version is 3.8 and recent installed in your environment, there should be no issue with the library.
Azure identity library - 1.16.1 is compatible with


Python 3.8 or a recent version of Python 3 (this library doesn't support end-of-life versions)


Run python --version to check the installed version and make sure that it is upgraded to the latest (3.12) to avoid conflicts.
As shown in the below image, DefaultAzureCredential

DefaultAzureCredential attempts to authenticate via the following mechanisms, in this order, stopping when one succeeds:


Make sure that you have not addedEnvironmentCredential() method in the code, because if it is present, it will always look for the AZURE_CLIENT_ID, and CLIENT_SECRET variables which might break things during authenticating to Azure.
Using Environment variables as shown in the below way with set command.
set AZURE_CLIENT_ID="xxxxx"
set AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="yyyy"
set AZURE_TENANT_ID="xxxx"
set SUBSCRIPTION_ID="yyyy"


Note: Make sure that you are executing the python in a virtual environment to avoid version related issues.
Activate it with below commands:
python -m venv .venv 
.venv/bin/activate

Also prefer using from  azure.identity  import  ClientSecretCredential method to directly set client_id & secret values in the code by creating an object.
By referring to the MSDoc, I tried authenticating to Azure and access Azure Storage with Python SDK identity library and was able to perform it successfully.
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
print(credential)
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(
       account_url="https://storenewj.blob.core.windows.net",
        credential=credential)
print("Authenticated successfully")


References:
SO by @Jake Boomgaarden
